# Restoring a div after using replace with on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem reverting this code, which replaces an image with a video on hover. On over out, I'd like it to go back to the original image.

I've tried numerous things but can't seem to get anything to work?

```
$("#video1, #video2, #video3, #video4, #video5, #video6, #video7, #video8, #video9, #video10, #video11, #video12, #video13, #video14, #video15, #video16, #video17, #video18, #video19, #video20 ").hover(function () 
{video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<article>

            <div class="img-video">
            <img src="images/thumb-theme.jpg" id="video1" alt="thumb" width="797" height="385" data-video="linktovideo.mp4">
            </div>

            <aside>
            <div class="title">
            <h3><a href="alink">Wording</a></h3>
            <div class="price">$14</div>
            </div>
            <p>Wording
```

Check it out

Comment: Why do you have to replace the image?

Comment: Why don't you just hide and show different elements, instead of replacing it?

Comment: @ksav Showing a preview video in it's place

Comment: Use class with same class name for video's, that will be better for selection

Comment: I would suggest doing what @Barmar suggests: hide and show elements on hover, instead of replacing elements in the DOM. 
Also, post some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = '';

$("#video1, #video2, #video3, #video4, #video5, #video6, #video7, #video8, #video9, #video10, #video11, #video12, #video13, #video14, #video15, #video16, #video17, #video18, #video19, #video20 ").hover(function () {
    video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    content = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith(video);

}, function() {
        $(this).html(content);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using toggle instead of replace. Something like this

```js
$(".panel1, .panel2, .panel3").hover(function () 
{
    $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1">
  <p>Original 1</p>
  <p style="display: none">Video 1</p>
</div>
<div class="panel2">
  <p>Original 2</p>
  <p style="display: none">Video 2</p>
</div>
<div class="panel3">
  <p>Original 3</p>
  <p style="display: none">Video 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well! However, once I hover out, the video keeps playing and then multiple videos overlay each other?

Comment: You can try using with  `document.getElementById(videoId)).pause();` Although I haven't found a solution yet.